# Recurse subpattern doesn't seem to work with alternation

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to match strings with numbers separated by commas. In a nutshell I want to match at most 8 numbers in range 1-16. So that string `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` is OK and `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` is not since it has 9 numbers. Also `16` is OK but `17` is not since 17 is not in range.

I tried to use this regex `^(?:(?:[1-9]|1[0-6]),){0,7}(?:[1-9]|1[0-6])$` 
and it worked fine. I use alternation to match numbers from 1-16, then I use 0..7 repetition with comma at the end and then the same without comma at the end. But I do not like the repetition of the subpattern, so I tried `(?1)` to recurse the first capturing group. My regex looks like `^(?:([1-9]|1[0-6]),){0,7}(?1)$`. However this do not produce match when the last number has two letters (10-16). It does match `1,1`, but not `1,10`. I do not understand why.

I created an example of the problem.

https://regex101.com/r/VkuPqP/1

In the debugger I see that the engine do not try the second alternation from the group, when the pattern recurse. I expect it to work. Where is the problem?

Comment: You can use PCRE2 version >= 10.30.
It makes subroutines Perl-like (non-atomic). And your regex must work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because the [regex subroutines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) in PCRE are atomic.

The regex you have can be re-written as `^(?:([1-9]|1[0-6]),){0,7}(?>[1-9]|1[0-6])$`, see [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/VkuPqP/2). `(?>...|...)` will not allow backtracking into this group, so if the first branch "wins" (as in your example), the subsequent ones will not be tried upon the next subpattern failure (here, `$` fails to match the end of string after matching `1` - it is followed with `0`).

You may swap the alternatives in this case, the longer should come first:

```
^(?:(1[0-6]|[1-9]),){0,7}(?1)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G0NydI/1).

In general, the best practice is that *each alternative in a group must match in different location inside a string*. They *should not match at the same locations*.

If you can't rewrite an alternation group so that each alternative matches at unique locations  in the string, you should repeat the group without using a regex subroutine.